# React Native production app stuck on splash screen

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I'm currently working on a React Native app, I finished the first version, published it to an expo release channel, built it and sent the .apk and .ipa to the stores.

Only issue i'm having is on iOS, sometimes ( on the first launch and randomly across devices ), my app just blocks on the splashscreen.

It doesn't happened in development mode, neither on the simulator and I can't find a way to get some logs about this issue.

I'm using sentry to get logs from my app, however, there's not a single line related to that crash so I'm tempted to say it's an issue with the js download from the expo channel but I've no clue.

Any help appreciated.

`"expo": "^27.0.0",`

`"react": "16.3.1",`

`"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-27.0.0.tar.gz",`

`"sentry-expo": "~1.7.0"`

edit: typo

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @GideonKitili Sorry for the late anwser, actualy the mistake was on my part, i was not updating my component well when I was doing the render test.